# Star-Trek-like series, where a man accidentally gets impregnated by an alien species

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, aliens, star-trek-voyager

I would have absolutely sworn that this was an episode from *Star Trek: Voyager*. However, I've just finished re-watching the entirety of *Voyager*, and the episode didn't happen! Either I managed to inadvertently skip over an episode, or it wasn't *Voyager* after all.

So details come in two parts:

- Bits that I'm "certain" of having existed which aren't absolutely tied to *Voyager*,
- Bits that I thought existed and do tie to *Voyager* specifically.

---

**Non-Voyager Specific**

Series Context: Something that involves the standard weekly cast regularly meeting aliens.

Episode Details:

- The cast meet a new, and broadly-friendly species.
- One (male) cast member gets particularly friendly with a female-equivalent member of the other species.
- The "female" alien invites the male cast member back to her room/quarters/etc. and then invites them to do a shared meditation/psychic link thing, in private.
- To the viewer it appears as a fake-out.... "Oh, they're going to have sex! Oh, no, they're just doing a some-what romantic meditation/link thing."
- The cast and the new species go their separate ways.
- Some time later... the male cast member starts to get weird symptoms and develops nipples on his forearm.
- The cast go back and find the aliens.
- It turns out that the meditation thing **was** (alien) sex, and the female alien assumed that they'd be biologically incompatible.
- Shockingly, by the end of the episode everything has been sorted out, and it never comes up again.

---

**Voyager-Specific**

- The "cast" in this case would be the Voyager's crew.
- I would have said the male cast member was either Tom Paris or Harry Kim.
- The aliens are another species on another starship.

Comment: How long ago was this?

Comment: I'm 32; I *probably* saw this at least 10 years ago, but I wouldn't swear to it.

Comment: So not https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HeDtQ9qWR4?

Comment: "*It turns out that the meditation thing was (alien) sex*" - shades of Ivanova in B5's "Acts of Sacrifice".

Comment: As the answers show it's not Voyager, but I think the reason you are thinking of Voyager is because there was a Voyager Episode, "The Disease" where Harry Kim is intimate with a female member of an alien species and starts getting "symptoms".

Comment: @Randal'Thor  Shades of Rick let Morty think Morty was torturing that alien for information....

Comment: the title had me thinking 1979's alien (the chestbuster)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is the ST: Enterprise episode [*Unexpected*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpected_(Star_Trek:_Enterprise)).

> A ship feeding off Enterprise's warp field is exposed after the crew
> ignites the plasma exhaust. Commander Tucker takes a trip to the ship
> to help them repair their warp drive. After his return to Enterprise,
> he learns that he is "pregnant". The nature of this event becomes a
> major plot device of the episode, and took the series into the realm
> of hard science fiction.

Comment: Aw man... I took too long exploring a bad lead off of https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MisterSeahorse

Comment: When Archer found out, did he say "Oh boy!"?

Comment: "... and took the series into the realm of hard science fiction." Ummm, what?? This is *Star Trek*, right? I can think of a million reasons why impregnation with alien genetic material *wouldn't work at all*. I don't understand that claim.

Comment: `took the series into the realm of hard science fiction`  Uh...yeah, I don't think so.  This is the same episode where the aliens gave Trip some synthesized jelly-like stuff to eat/drink claiming it was *"the closest they could come to water"*.  As though aliens had never heard of hydrogen or oxygen before...

Comment: @BMF  Teh qite may have meant "hard to believe science fiction" or something like that.

Comment: After a first sentence with needless techobabble, I didn't have much hope for the rest of that summary.

Answer (score 10):

Unexpected
Star Trek: Enterprise episode (season 1, episode 4)

Trip gets pregnant.   You are correct the series is only star trek like.

Comment: But it's also canon star-trek. The Enterprise, Vulcans and Klingons, Andorreans, "go to  warp 3.2", transporters. Overuse of time-travel. "Star-trek like" is a real misdirect in the Q.

Comment: @OwenReynolds - I suspect that lucasbachmann was being snarky. In much the same way that I consider Picard and Discovery to be non-canon, but know in my heart of hearts that that just isn't true.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like VOY 5x17 "[The Disease](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Disease_(episode))". Harry Kim experiences a biological linkage after a sex-adjacent experience on a generation ship.

Comment: The OP has already [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/249834/122024), as denoted by the green check mark visible to the immediate left of that answer. As such, it's unlikely that your answer is the episode the OP had in mind.

Comment: I'm aware  Given the specificity of the VOY references, though, I thought it worth of a top level answer.

Comment: @jkingsman - I felt it was worthy of an answer (and an upvote). There's certainly some similarities between the two episodes and we know that OP has seen Voyager. He could easily be conflating them both.

Comment: It does seem very possible that the OP saw _both_ of these episodes, and that this contributed to his confusion over which series the episode he was looking for occurred in. But given that his description specifically mentioned the male crew member being impregnated and developing nipples on his forearms, it's all but certain that he was thinking of the _Enterprise_ episode. The _Voyager_ episode was certainly worth mentioning in a comment, but [another user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/134806/andy) already did that yesterday.

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have called out that I'd see "The Disease" and (whilst similar) it's definitely not that. FWIW I'd say that this *is* worth offering as a full answer. We have methods of expressing which answer is "best" and having this record here of a *possible* answer may help future users that were looking for this answer, with similar search keywords.

Comment: (Much like poker - the fact that your answer didn't "win" doesn't mean it was a bad answer)